# Nginx and PhpMyAdmin - Redirect to images

Tags: image, nginx, phpmyadmin

I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04. I installed Tomcat 7 as a server and Nginx as a reverse proxy. Then I also installed PhpMyAdmin and got that working. The only problem I now have is that none of the images for PhpMyAdmin is showing. I've done a lot of searching on this issue and have found several ways to fix it but none of them work for particular instance. I set up my Nginx configuration in such a way that any request gets forwarded to my Tomcat server except when it ends in `.php`, in which case it forwards (correctly) to PhpMyAdmin. Here's (the important parts) of my nginx configuration (`etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name 123.123.123.123; # fake Ip address
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://tomcat_server;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I have a very basic knowledge of the above, so excuse me for not knowing how the location closures really work or what their contents do.

What I think I need to do is rewrite those to location closures in such a way that requests containing `/phpmyadmin/ + anything here + .png` or `.jpg`, etc gets forwarded to the right directory. Please let me know if this is not the best way of doing it though. Otherwise please let me know how to rewrite my location closures to do what I want it to do. It seems that PhpMyAdmin's images are stored at `/usr/share/nginx/html/phpmyadmin/themes/` if that helps. Let me know if I need to supply any additional information.

Comment: You probably need to add `location /phpmyadmin/ { }`. Literally an empty block should do it.

Comment: The reason it didn't work earlier was `/phpmyadmin/` was being sent to your tomcat server. because the location matches `/`. Adding a blank block `location /phpmyadmin/ { }` meant that the block inherited `root /usr/share/nginx/html;` and when you request that location nginx will check for files in that location and serve them. So now your `/phpmyadmin` request don't go to tomcat instead they are server from the disk. php files still go to the old block.